# WPF - MVVM - Return Bindable Control Template from View Model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to display available Wifi networks (using ManagedWifi SDK) on a listview.

I have defined ObservableCollection of WifiNetwork (contains name, type, signal Strength(int) etc) in my viewmodel as shown below

```
public ObservableCollection<WifiNetwork> AvailableNetworks { get; set; }
```

I have defined Control templates (like 1 green bar and 4 white bars to indicate signal strength <= 20%, 2 green bars and 3 white bars to indicate signal strength between 20 to 40% etc) in Application Resources in app.xaml as shown below

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="Signal1">
    <Canvas Width="32" Height="32" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0">
        <Rectangle Width="5.4375" Height="11.375" Canvas.Left="0.0937499" Canvas.Top="20.6563" Stretch="Fill" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000" Fill="#FF37F307"/>
        <Rectangle Width="6.40625" Height="16" Canvas.Left="5.34375" Canvas.Top="16.0313" Stretch="Fill" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000" Fill="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        <Path Width="6.88835" Height="21.6562" Canvas.Left="11.75" Canvas.Top="10.375" Stretch="Fill" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Data="F1 M 12.2768,10.875L 18.1384,10.875L 18.1115,31.5313L 12.25,31.5313L 12.2768,10.875 Z "/>
        <Rectangle Width="6.78126" Height="26.9687" Canvas.Left="18.5625" Canvas.Top="5.09376" Stretch="Fill" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000" Fill="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        <Rectangle Width="6.71874" Height="31.8437" Canvas.Left="25.2812" Canvas.Top="0.250002" Stretch="Fill" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000" Fill="#FFFFFFFF"/>
    </Canvas>
</ControlTemplate>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="Signal2">
    <Canvas Width="32" Height="32" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0">
        <Rectangle Width="5.4375" Height="11.375" Canvas.Left="0.0937499" Canvas.Top="20.6563" Stretch="Fill" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000" Fill="#FF37F307"/>
        <Rectangle Width="6.40625" Height="16" Canvas.Left="5.34375" Canvas.Top="16.0313" Stretch="Fill" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000" Fill="#FF37F307"/>
        <Path Width="6.88835" Height="21.6562" Canvas.Left="11.75" Canvas.Top="10.375" Stretch="Fill" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Data="F1 M 12.2768,10.875L 18.1384,10.875L 18.1115,31.5313L 12.25,31.5313L 12.2768,10.875 Z "/>
        <Rectangle Width="6.78126" Height="26.9687" Canvas.Left="18.5625" Canvas.Top="5.09376" Stretch="Fill" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000" Fill="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        <Rectangle Width="6.71874" Height="31.8437" Canvas.Left="25.2812" Canvas.Top="0.250002" Stretch="Fill" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000" Fill="#FFFFFFFF"/>
    </Canvas>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Now I need to return this control template from my view model to bind it to a button to show the appropriate signal strength in my listBox.

I probably need to have some kind of conversion from Signal Strength (int) to Control template.

Any suggestions / code examples to achieve this task?

Comment: Given that your view **model** should not know about WPF, you have a bigger issue with your design.

Answer (score 1):

This should guide to right direction:

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableNetworks }">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Rectangle Width="20" Height="{Binding SignalStrength,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                     Fill="{Binding Color,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></Rectangle>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

I like Darek's answer, but if you really want to use control templates like this, you should use a style and a data trigger bound to the signal strength, e.g.:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type MyControl}">
   <Style.Triggers>
       <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SignalStrength}" Value="1">
          <Setter Property="ControlTemplate" Value="{StaticResource Signal1}"/>
       </DataTrigger>
       <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SignalStrength}" Value="2">
          <Setter Property="ControlTemplate" Value="{StaticResource Signal2}"/>
       </DataTrigger>
       <!-- and so on -->
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to just use a ItemTemplate on your listbox and to create a converter class.

Create a public class called ColorConverter and use the following code in it:

```
public class ColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region Implementation of IValueConverter

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            var val = System.Convert.ToInt32(value.ToString());
            var param = System.Convert.ToInt32(parameter.ToString());

            return val >= param ? Brushes.Green : Brushes.White;

        }
        catch
        {
            return Brushes.White;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then on the page with the ListBox assign the converter:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Converters:ColorConverter x:Key="colorConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Make sure you put the namespace for "Converters" at the top of the xaml:

```
xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:ProjectNameHere"
```

Then create a DataTemplate on your listbox using your code above, substituting the bindings to the correct forms:

```
<ListBox Margin="0,73,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableNetworks}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Canvas Width="32"
                        Height="32"
                        Canvas.Left="0"
                        Canvas.Top="0">
                    <Rectangle Width="5.4375"
                               Height="11.375"
                               Canvas.Left="0.0937499"
                               Canvas.Top="20.6563"
                               Stretch="Fill"
                               StrokeLineJoin="Round"
                               Stroke="#FF000000"
                               Fill="{Binding Strength, Converter={StaticResource colorConverter}, ConverterParameter=0}" />
                    <Rectangle Width="6.40625"
                               Height="16"
                               Canvas.Left="5.34375"
                               Canvas.Top="16.0313"
                               Stretch="Fill"
                               StrokeLineJoin="Round"
                               Stroke="#FF000000"
                               Fill="{Binding Strength, Converter={StaticResource colorConverter}, ConverterParameter=20}" />
                    <Path Width="6.88835"
                          Height="21.6562"
                          Canvas.Left="11.75"
                          Canvas.Top="10.375"
                          Stretch="Fill"
                          StrokeLineJoin="Round"
                          Stroke="#FF000000"
                          Fill="{Binding Strength, Converter={StaticResource colorConverter}, ConverterParameter=40}"
                          Data="F1 M 12.2768,10.875L 18.1384,10.875L 18.1115,31.5313L 12.25,31.5313L 12.2768,10.875 Z " />
                    <Rectangle Width="6.78126"
                               Height="26.9687"
                               Canvas.Left="18.5625"
                               Canvas.Top="5.09376"
                               Stretch="Fill"
                               StrokeLineJoin="Round"
                               Stroke="#FF000000"
                               Fill="{Binding Strength, Converter={StaticResource colorConverter}, ConverterParameter=60}" />
                    <Rectangle Width="6.71874"
                               Height="31.8437"
                               Canvas.Left="25.2812"
                               Canvas.Top="0.250002"
                               Stretch="Fill"
                               StrokeLineJoin="Round"
                               Stroke="#FF000000"
                               Fill="{Binding Strength, Converter={StaticResource colorConverter}, ConverterParameter=80}" />
                </Canvas>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

The down side to doing it this way is the lack of style reuse, unlike the other methods mentioned.